# What is the field of a magnetic dipole near a conducting sphere?

Tags: electromagnetism, conductors, dipole, magnetostatics

Suppose I have a perfectly conducting sphere in vacuum, and I place a magnetic dipole near this sphere. Simply stated, the magnetic field of the dipole will be distorted by the presence of the conducting sphere. I want to know how to properly start off the calculations for finding the resultant magnetic field.

The current density in the surrounding space (which is a vacuum) $J=0$. This gives us a curl-free magnetic field vector $\mathbf{B}$, and hence, we can write $\mathbf{B} = - \nabla \Psi$, where $\Psi$ is the magnetic scalar potential. I also know that the magnetic scalar potential of an isolated magnetic dipole will be

\begin{equation}
\psi = \frac{\mathbf{m.r}}{4\pi |\mathbf{r}|^3}
\end{equation}

But, how do I correctly construct $\Psi$ using $\psi$ and the appropriate boundary conditions for conductors? Or is this even the right way to approach the problem?

Comment: If it's truly a "perfectly conducting sphere," i.e. a superconductor at absolute zero, then a surface current should emerge the perfectly cancels out any B field inside. Use the normal boundary conditions to determine $\vec{J}$ at the surface

Comment: @SeñorO I have tried unsuccessfully to compute the surface current. Could you please elaborate on the method that you are proposing? Can the magnetic field of the external dipole be used to calculate the surface current using boundary conditions $\mu_0 \mathbf{J} = \hat{n} \times \mathbf{B}$ and $\hat{n}.\mathbf{B} = 0$ or do I instead go around solving the problem by calculating the resultant magnetic potential from the solutions of Laplace equation?